# Cannot find module "@angular/core" and its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular

I'm making a website using ASP.NET 5 and Angular. I created an MVC template in Visual Studio and add Angular Template as an existing website. But some modules went missing. For instance,

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
```

gets an error

> Cannot find module "@angular/core" or its corresponding type declarations.

How can I deal with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It happened when I missed the node_modules folder. So I opened the terminal and run `npm install`. If it gets errors, downgrade NodeJs because your current NodeJS is not compatible with your current Angular framework. I had installed Node JS v16, the newest version of Node then, after getting errors, I installed Node JS v14 with highly recommended. It worked.